# overlay dependent options in tikz commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

This is something that should be a FAQ, but which I have not found an answer to here or elsewhere. I frequently wish to write things like

```
\draw[fill=\alt<2>{red}{white}] ...
```

but I have never found a way to get expanded values into the value of a command option.

There are ways to work round it, such as embedding entire commands inside an `\alt`, but I would rather write something simple and obvious.

Am I missing such a thing?

Comment: Look at the `overlay-beamer-styles` library (e.g. with `texdoc aobs`). (You can also force expansion by doing something like `fill/.expanded=...`, but I am not sure that this works in this case.).

Comment: Thank you! I have come across user Daniel in previous explorations of animating pictures, but not seen this extension of his work.
Yes indeed, `.expanded` does not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already mentioned, the `overlay-beamer-styles` library has many amazing tools allowing one to work with overlays in `tikz`. With this library you could use something like

```
\draw[background fill=red,fill on=<2>] ...
```

However, to address your question literally one could also define a new key handler, `/.alt`, with which the above becomes

```
\draw[fill/.alt=<2>{red}{none}] ...
```

This new (?) key handler is defined and used in the following example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{%
        \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath=#2}%
        }{%
        \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath=#3}%
        }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The \texttt{/.alt} key handler}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill/.alt=<2>{red}{none}] circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This key handler could be more useful in situations that were not anticipated by `overlay-beamer-styles`. One could also create a similar key handler for `\only`, which may be more appropriate in situations in which you only want to do something on certain overlays and nothings on the remaining overlays.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to highlight one option the `overlay-beamer-styles` library enables, as it seams like a compromise between the options user255043 mentions.

There is an `alt` option included, so one could write the following with the same result as shown by user255043.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{The \texttt{alt} }
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[alt=<2>{fill=red}] circle[radius=1];
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Did not yet read the documentation of `overlay-beamer-styles`, but `alt=<1>{alternative}{default}` takes two arguments, like the one from the `beamer` class and can be defined multiple times:

`\draw[alt=<2>{fill=red}{fill=blue, draw=red}, alt=<5>{fill=green, very thick}] circle[radius=1];`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!